# Hibernate Entities Mapping NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, object, jakarta-ee, mapping

Hej Guys, here is my problem. I have a piece of code in Java and I don't know
what's the reason of NullPointerException. I suppouse it's caused by incorrect objects mapping
but I haven't found solution on my own yet.

```
ArrayList<Auction> auctionList = auctionDAO.findAll();  /* Works correctly */

for(Auction auction : auctionList) {
System.out.println(auction.getOwner().getEmail());  /* NullPointerException */
}

/* -------------- ENTITIES --------------- */

@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    (other properties)
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="owner")
    @JoinTable(
            name="OWNER_AUCTION",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="OWNER_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="AUCTION_ID")
    )
    private Set<Auction> ownedAuctionList = new HashSet<Auction>();

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    (getters & setters)
}

@Entity
@Table(name="AUCTIONS")
public class Auction implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    (other properties)

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private User owner;

    (other properties & getters & setters)
}
```

Comment: Can you share your tables?

Comment: If auction is not null so auction.getOwner() might return null value. Make sure that auction.getOwner() is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Without your tables, it's hard to say. But i guess for debugging purpose you should do something like that:

```
for(Auction auction : auctionList) {
    if(auction.getOwner()==null){
        System.out.println("Null Owner");
    }
    else if(auction.getOwner().getEmail()==null){
        System.out.println("Null mail");
    }
    else
    System.out.println(auction.getOwner().getEmail());
}
```

This should help you find your issue

Comment: Thanks reply. I found mistake. It was a little bug beacause of my oversigt. Nothing special.